# Facets display values instead of labels

Tags: 7, search

I am using the [facets module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets) to add filter blocks in my view.

I have a list field wich contains

> FR|France
>
> IT|Italy

My dropdown list of facet display values (fr, it)

I want to display (France, Italy)

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Something preventing changing the keys from FR IT to France Italy ?

Comment: it's a very long list :)

Answer (score 0):

try in search API > your index > search your field and then in the column type, select STRING.

Also maybe you can hook your field:

```
function HOOK_facet_items_alter(&$build, &$settings) {
   if ($settings->facet == "YOUR_FACET_NAME") {
       foreach($build as $key => $item) {
          $build[$key]["#markup"] = drupal_strtoupper($item["#markup"]);
        }
    }
}
```